# New field based on sum field

Tags: mysql, select, sum

I'm trying to create a new field based in another (sum field)

```
SELECT sum(price) AS old_price,
   old_price+100 AS total_price
FROM sales
```

This returns **Unknown column 'old_price' in 'field list'**

`sum` is just a example, my real issue is to use with a select inside this field

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

--edit
I've used variables to reuse the alias, updated code:

```
SELECT @old_price := sum(price) AS old_price,
   @old_price+100 AS total_price
FROM sales
```

If you think that it is not a good practice, tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't do anything wrong.
Unfortunately, referencing calculated columns in the field list is just not possible.

The usual workaround is to use self joins, joins to subselects or anything like that. But that would only qualify for more complex calculations. In your case, the solution would be to just write it the way Ryan mentioned, even if that turns the stomach of every programmer.

Comment: Yea, you're right.. and what about using variables?

Comment: Behavior for this is undefined, from the mysql docs: **As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement.** (from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, columns in the select-list cannot reference other columns by alias. This is standard SQL.

MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of the select-list from left to right, so it would not be a recommended practice to use variables like you show.

Another workaround is to do computations and create column aliases in a derived table, and then reference them in the outer query. This is standard SQL and is reliable.

```
SELECT old_price, old_price + 100 AS total_price
FROM (
    SELECT sum(price) AS old_price FROM sales
) AS t;
```

Comment: Great! what if I need to use one more derivated table for calculate?

Comment: You can keep nesting derived tables if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are wanting to do is:

```
SELECT sum(price) + 100 AS total_price FROM sales
```

Otherwise your query is looking for old_price as it's own column name when you are doing old_price+100

EDIT:

```
SELECT sum(price) AS old_price, sum(price) + 100 AS total_price FROM sales
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not allowed to downvote or comment or upvote (lol) on anything, so the only way I can contribute here is to add an answer. Some of these answers are devoid of fact.

You cannot do the following:

```sql
SELECT sum(price) AS old_price, sum(price) + 100 AS total_price FROM sales
```

Here is the error you will recieve if you attempt to do this.

> Unknown column 'old_price'

MySQL does not allow you to assign a name to a computed sum like this.

After attempting Bill Karwin's suggestion I also see that this does not work. The error you will receive is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near SELECT sum(price) AS old_price FROM sales

These simply do not answer the question and provide false information.

The correct answer is Oliver Rahner's. You can not do this at all.

Comment: Normally I would vote to delete this, but I  think it adds something valuable, to the mix.

Comment: Hopefully someone else won't waste time looking into what these other people said just because they have upvotes.